# Calling php.exe process via psexec and hiding window

Tags: php, windows

I'm trying to call a php script via psexec (I need to fork/detach the process, and in Windows it's the only way I managed to do it). It all works fine, but it pops up a console window that I'd like to hide. I've tried both using the start command, and also downloaded nircmd, neither of which worked (meaning, command runs fine, but window always pops up). I'm looking for any other way of making this work. Or maybe my calls are just wrong. Here are some examples of calls I tried:

```
nircmdc exec hide psexec.exe -i -accepteula -w "c:\MyApp" -d "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v7.0.4\php.exe" app.php start test
```

I then tried putting the command in a batch file and using nircmd to call that:

```
nircmdc exec hide startWorker.bat "c:\MyApp" "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v7.0.4\php.exe" test
--startWorker.bat--
psexec.exe -i -accepteula -w %1 -d %2 app.php start %3
```

Finally, I tried the start command:

```
start "Worker" /d "c:\MyApp\lib\bin" /b psexec -accepteula -w "c:\MyApp" -d "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v7.0.4\php.exe" app.php start test
```

Again, all of the commands above successfully run the app, they just don't hide the window. I'm trying this on Windows 7.

Comment: start /MIN .... will hide the window for you/

Comment: I just tried start "Worker" /MIN /d "c:\MyApp\lib\bin" /b psexec -accepteula -w "c:\MyApp" -d "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v7.0.4\php.exe" app.php start test, it didn't work

Comment: PSEXEC is starting another process which is showing the window.
Remove PSEXEC and try with  a simple solution like I said above, 
Then you need to figure out whether you really need to use PSEXEC or 
the parameters to PSEXEC that will run with window minimized

Comment: @dgorti I have already figured out that I need PSEXEC, unless somebody knows of another way to run a detached process on Windows. It's the only solution I've found so far that's simple and works.

Comment: Define "detached" process please...

Comment: @dgorti A detached process means that if I kill the process that launched them, they live on. Right now, I call a PHP console app doing something like php app.php, which is a console app that runs in an endless loop and can call exec() and spawn other php.exe processes. However, if I quit main process (CTRL+C or otherwise), all php.exe processes it created are killed too. By using PSEXEC, the processes live on.